# passing a TextBlock or collection of inlines to a child UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, textblock

I have created a UserControl called InfoBox that acts like a fancy textblock (extra buttons etc). It works fine. I can use it in Blend like so:

```
<myNS:InfoBox Text="Some Text"/>
```

where 'Text' is a dependency property:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(InfoBox),
     new UIPropertyMetadata(null,ValueChanged));
```

and handled like so:

```
    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject dpo,
                                     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ((InfoBox)dpo).TextBlock.Text = (string)args.NewValue;
    }
```

When I add the control in Blend, it shows up with its design-time sample text, until I specify Text="Something", in which case "Something" magically shows up in the designer. Perfect!

But now I want to pass more than text, I want to be able to use all the funky functionality you get inline with a textblock. Run, italic, etc...

Why does the following not work?

```
<myNS:InfoBox>
        <myNS:InfoBox.ReferenceBlock>
             <TextBlock>
                <Run Language="en-gb" Text="SampleSample"/><LineBreak/>
                <Run Language="en-gb"/><LineBreak/>
                <Run Language="en-gb" Text="MoreMoreMore"/>
             </TextBlock>   
        <myNS:InfoBox.ReferenceBlock>           
</myNS:InfoBox>
```

.

```
     public static readonly DependencyProperty ReferenceBlockProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ReferenceBlock", typeof(TextBlock), 
        typeof(InfoBox), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, ReferenceBlockReceived));

[...]


     private static void ReferenceBlockReceived(DependencyObject dpo,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var textblock = (TextBlock)args.NewValue;
        if (textblock != null)
        {
            ((InfoBox)dpo).TextBlock.Inlines.Clear();
            ((InfoBox)dpo).TextBlock.Inlines.AddRange(textblock.Inlines);
        }
    }
```

The TextBlock received by the handler is completely empty for some reason. I appreciate any help. This WPF stuff is tough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not so simple.  `TextBlock` supports elements of type *Run* through a dependency property called *Inlines* along with a couple of interfaces.  It would be possible but difficult to reproduce this behaviour in your fancy text box.

I recommend you download Jetbrain's free decompiler [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) which will allow you to study the implementation of TextBlock for an idea of what's required.

Comment: I'm not really trying to reproduce the behaviour, but rather pass an instance or a copy of an instance of textblock into my control. Not sure why this would not be possible? In any case I will look at dotpeek, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Further to Phil's answer, I would suggest changing the type of your `ReferenceBlock` dependency property to `object`, then within your custom control use a `ContentControl` with the `Content` property bound to `ReferenceBlock` - this will allow you to pass in arbitrary content, including multiple lines of text:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="myNS:InfoBox">
    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding ReferenceBlock}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

This would also allow you to pass in images/controls/other content as required.